# How to enable client credentials grant type in laravel passport

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I am trying to develop a restful api using token for authentication using laravel 5.3 . I have also added laravel passport and I thought it will help me build the api faster. The resource I would like to give through api is common to all users , nothing specific to the user. So figured I should use grant type : client credentials.   I couldn't find the any help about this grant type in laravel documentation

https://github.com/laravel/passport/pull/34/files this link shows the client credential grant type  is added to laravel passport . but when I try to give grant type as client credential

```
    $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
    $response = $http->post('http://site.dev/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            'client_id' => config('api.client_id'),
            'client_secret' => config('api.client_secret'),
            'redirect_uri' => config('api.redirect_uri'),
     ],
    ]);
```

it gives error in grant type used.

Comment: I think i should go with password grant type.

Comment: I have created a client using password grant and edited the database table column password_client , changed 1 -> 0. and it return api token. how to create password client ? there is only option using php artsan command

Answer (score 2):

I was using client credentials method because it was a machine to machine call. I got error like { "error": "Unauthenticated." }` when using postman. I used Access type and Authorization headers but was getting the same error. Then I googled and tried the method explained in below link. It worked. :) :) http://filljoyner.com/2017/03/01/how-to-use-client-credentials-grant-tokens-for-your-api-authorization-with-laravel-5-4s-passport/

Comment: You should use the comment for this type of suggestions.  if you are answering then please explain.

Answer (score 1):

When you install Laravel Passport one password grant in installed by default in oath_clients table, but password_client column should be 1 not 0.
Then you send [some](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#password-grant-tokens) form_data to `/oauth/token` url and get `access_token` in return.

Comment: only way to create password grant is php artisan passport:client --password.  I want to create password clients from admin side. I think more docs and codes will be added in the next passport update completely implementing all four grants